# .net 4.8 HttpClient still fails after network is restored

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.8

Repro steps:

1. Turn off network by disabling the network adapter
2. Start a httplient request with a cancellation, sure the SendAsync task will be cancelled.
3. Turn on network, redo step 2, keeps failing.

What I have tried:

1. set cache to false
2. add a random number as a a=xxx parameter to the end of the url.
3. set `ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0`
4. create HttpClient with `IHttpClientFactory`

I am using .net 4.8 with just the simple HttpClient code as below:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
    AllowTrailingCommas = true,
};
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync(url, typeof(MyType), options, cancellationToken) as MyType;
```

or

```
await httpClientFactory.CreateClient().GetFromJsonAsync(url, typeof(MyType), options, cancellationToken) as MyType;
```

It keeps failing with this error:

> A task was canceled

and the InnerException is null. Any ideas?

Comment: HttpClient will cache DNS, you need to create a new HttpClient/HttpMessageHandler, or use [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)

Comment: Failed with what specific error?

Comment: That code won't even compile. No [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-8.0) accepts a Url as the first paramerer. Even if this is [PostAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=net-8.0), it's never awaited so there's no way to know if the request worked, was cancelled or failed. `xxx` can't be an arbitrary object, it has to be an HttpContent object.

Comment: @Adyson, same, "A task was canceled", because I passed a cancellationToken

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your reply, I just showed the example code, it's not for product compiling. no matter sendasync or postasync, it's not the root cause.

Comment: `same, "A task was canceled"`...ok, thanks. We didn't know it was the same though, because you never mentioned the error in the first place. You should [edit] your question to include the _exact, full_ error message clearly within the question itself (not hidden down in the comments). Also, was there not an inner exception you can also report? Sometimes that can give more details.

Comment: @MingTong we can't even guess what the root cause is from an incorrect snippet and no problem description. There's no information in this question. For all we know the code is calling a non-existent host. Or the request may be working but the code never even checks the response. Or, due to the lack of `await`, the method exits and HttpClient gets disposed before a response is received

Comment: @ADyson, ye, thanks for your suggestion, I just added more details. and unfortunately, there is no inner exception.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks, I just modified the description to make it clear to read.

Comment: The problem isn't readability. It's the incomplete code, faulty code. `GetFromJsonAsync` is never awaited so the calling method will exit before the request completes. `httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync() as MyType;` will always return `null` because `MyType` isn't a Task. We can't guess where `cancellationToken` comes from. Perhaps it comes from a CTS with too short a timeout. Or the address is wrong. DNS resolution can take up to 15 seconds.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks, I just felt no need to post the full code here, edit again, I set the cts as cancel task after 15 sec, but it never hit the 15 sec, just 5 sec, will throw the "A task was cancelled". by the way, what does this mean "DNS resolution can take up to 15 seconds"?

Comment: @shingo, I tried to use httpClientFactory.CreateClient() in each request, it still.

Comment: `I just felt no need to post the full code here`...you need to post at least a [mre] of the issue that we can comprehend :-)

Comment: HTTP requests are made to IP addresses, not URLs. When you make any network request using an address like `stackoverflow.com`, whether it's through HttpClient or the command line, the computer has to resolve that host name to an IP. If the computer doesn't have the IP in its local cache it will ask the network's DNS server. If the DNS server doesn't have the address it will check an upstream server before answering. That can take up to 15 seconds before it times out. If you use a non-existend address like `banana.boo` the DNS servers will keep asking each other until a root says that's invalid

Comment: What happens if you *don't* use a CancellationToken at all? [HttpClient.Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-8.0) is 100s for a reason.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, after removed the CancellationToken, it got working.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I added the CancellationToken back, but set the CancelAfter(100seconds), it is still working.

Comment: So...basically you previously did not give your request long enough to complete. How long is it taking now? Can you tell? I don't know if your code is trying to read the JSON it receives after the `await` or not.

Comment: @MingTong try to wait 100s and call CreateClient again.

Comment: @ADyson, I don't what is the completion for a failure, when I set the CancelAfter(15 seconds), it just throw exception after 5 seconds for the first try, and even after I restored the network, it will immediately throw the same exception.
For now, it will wait for 100s to fail, and after I restore the network, it will get succeed after 3 seconds.

Comment: @shingo, thanks, it is working now based on 100s.

Comment: Why not just remove the cancellationToken like you did before? How long does it take to fail then?

Comment: @ADyson, it will take the full 100s to fail.
if the network is available, in some case I still need a way to cancel a running http request, otherwise the http request will be there until it finished.

Comment: Try setting the shortest timeout value which reliably works, then

Comment: @ADyson, even I set the timeout to 60s, will not work.